# How do you translate: "diploma date" or "diploma issued date" or "graduation date"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Do you know how you say "diploma date" or "diploma issued date" or "graduation date" in french?

Is just a short expression which I will include in a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say *Date d'obtention du diplôme*, or just *Date d'obtention* if not ambiguous (if it is in a diploma section, for instance).

This is what I use to see in official forms.

Comment: If the previous field is "Diplôme:" you can just use "Obtenu le:" which is clear in context.